# Create mysql database with Django using Docker

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I am stuck with deploying my Django project which uses mySQL database using docker containers.

I am able to create the two containers but the `web` container exits with code 1 as soon as it is created with the error -- **`Not able to find tg_db database`**.

My understanding is that when I run `docker-compose up -d` to start both the containers, it uses `MYSQL_DATABASE=tg_db` environment variable to create the database named **tg_db**, which is used and identified by django settings. Or, I can run command `docker-compose run web python3 manage.py migrate` to run docker-compose which will create database and migrations on it. Please let me know, if this is not true.

Below are the files used:

`settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'tg_db',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB;'}
},}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
    # Start with a python image
    FROM python:3

    # Some stuff that everyone has been copy-pasting
    # since the dawn of time.
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

    # Install things
    RUN apt-get update

    # Make folders and locations for project

    RUN mkdir /code
    COPY . /code
    WORKDIR /code/project/t_backend

    # Install requirements

    RUN pip install -U pip
    RUN pip install -Ur requirements.txt
```

Woking directory is set to `WORKDIR /code/project/t_backend` as my `manage.py` sits there and Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files lives at the same place as project folder.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=tg_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Thank's in advance!

Comment: It seems it just typo in env variable. It is `MYSQL_DATABSE`, but should be `MYSQL_DATABASE`.

Comment: @Nickolay: My bad ! I corrected the typo.. but still I get the same error after both the containers are built. Error is:
`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'tg_db'")`

Command I used to run : `sudo docker-compose run web python3 manage.py migrate`

Comment: @Nickolay
The issue seems that it is not able to create database in `db` container, and I am not sure how to link the two containers, so this works!

Comment: sorry, it's not clear, if issue was fixed or not.

Comment: @Nickolay No, the issue is not fixed. After correcting typo in `docker-compose`, I get the same error. 

How do you create database while dockerizing an application. Any other steps apart from one mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes, that's enough and should work. Maybe new env was not applied? Do `docker-compose down`, then `docker-compose up -d`. And if it still doesn't work, check if database exists in mysql container.

Comment: @Nickolay I checked that in mysql container. The database doesn't exists there. Do I have to create the database manually there as well ?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is, so I created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let me describe your case step by step.

**1.** It was a typo in the `docker-compose.yaml` file where `MYSQL_DATABSE=tg_db` was written instead of `MYSQL_DATABASE=tg_db`.

**2.** `docker-compose up -d` was performed and both containers were started. Of course, database `tg_db` was never created.

**3.** According to the `docker-compose.yaml` file, the folder `./dbdata` from the host machine mounts to `/var/lib/mysql` inside container. So, when containers were created in previous step, all mysql data was written to folder `/var/lib/mysql` in container and to `./dbdata` folder on the host machine. This data didn't have `tg_db` database, because of the typo in step 1:

```
$ ls -la dbdata/
total 176196
drwxrwxr-x 5 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     4096 Apr  8 21:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 np           np               4096 Apr  8 21:17 ..
-rw-r----- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj       56 Apr  8 21:17 auto.cnf
-rw------- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1675 Apr  8 21:17 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1107 Apr  8 21:17 ca.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1107 Apr  8 21:17 client-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1679 Apr  8 21:17 client-key.pem
-rw-r----- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj      662 Apr  8 21:18 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj 79691776 Apr  8 21:18 ibdata1
-rw-r----- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj 50331648 Apr  8 21:18 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj 50331648 Apr  8 21:17 ib_logfile1
drwxr-x--- 2 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     4096 Apr  8 21:17 mysql
drwxr-x--- 2 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     4096 Apr  8 21:17 performance_schema
-rw------- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1679 Apr  8 21:17 private_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj      451 Apr  8 21:17 public_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1107 Apr  8 21:17 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj     1679 Apr  8 21:17 server-key.pem
drwxr-x--- 2 guest-ryx1oj guest-ryx1oj    12288 Apr  8 21:17 sys
```

**4.** Typo was corrected (a correct environment variable name was set) and stack was re-created:

```
docker-compose down
docker compose up -d
```

But when that was done the `./dbdata` folder with the data from the previous attempt was mounted again to container's `/var/lib/mysql` and overrided the data, that was created there during container start. And of course, data in mounted folder didn't have `tg_db` database.

**Solution:**

Please delete all the data from `./dbdata` folder on the host machine (I hope it is just a period of tests, so data there isn't important and could be deleted) and re-create your stack again:

```
docker-compose down
rm -vrf ./dbdata/*
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: And what if I have two mysql databases in my django app. How will I use `docker-compose` to create other database named `tg_search_db`?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can create only one db using environment variables when container starts.